# If $7^z=8, 2^x=5$ and $5^y=7$ then $4x^3=\;?$ (without using logarithms)

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

If $7^z=8, 2^x=5$, and $5^y=7$, then $4x^3=\;?$ (without using logarithms).

Comment: In [your recently deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3486633/potent-without-log), I wrote "Without logarithms, you should not expect there to be an algebraic solution.".

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't saw, your answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have \begin{align}
\color{blue}{2^x}&=\color{red}5\tag1\\
\color{red}5^y&=7\tag2\\
(\color{blue}{2^x})^y&=7\\
\color{green}{2^{xy}}&=\color{blue}7\\
\color{blue}7^z&=8\tag3\\
(\color{green}{2^{xy}})^z&=8\\
2^{xyz}&=8\\
2^{xyz}&=2^3\implies xyz=3\implies x=\frac3{yz}
\end{align}

As such, $$4x^3=4\left(\frac3{yz}\right)^3=\frac{108}{y^3z^3}.$$

This is as good as it gets.